# extending local systems on a neighbourhood

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, schemes, galois-representations

Let $Y$ an affine finite type scheme over an algebraically closed field $k$.
Let $S$ be a closed subscheme of $Y$ and $Y'$ the henselization of $Y$ along $S$.
If we have a $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$ local system on $Y'$, does it come from a $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$ local system on some étale neighbourhood $U\rightarrow Y$ of $S$?

I guess in the case where $S\rightarrow Y$ is a regular immersion it should be true, as for the étale topology I can find a map in the other direction.

Comment: this is a really interesting question! I think the answer should be no in the case where $Y$ is an elliptic surface minus a section and $S$ is one of the fibers, but I didn't figure out how to prove it.